# vswprintf : Mac %s vs Windows %S

Tags: stdstring, wchar-t, printf

I'm using vswprintf to form a wchar_t* str from a formatted string. In that formatted string, to print a std:string, Mac accepts as %s while Windows VS2008 accepts as %S. Example

```
void widePrint(const wchar_t* fmt, ...) { 
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    wchar_t buf[32*1024] = {0};

    vswprintf(buf,(32*1024 - 1),fmt, args);

    ...//Prints buf 
    ...
}
...
std::string str = "normal String";
std::wstring strW = L"wideStr";
widePrint(L"str: %S wStr: %ls",str.c_str(), strW.c_str()); //Windows - VS2008
widePrint(L"str: %s wStr: %ls",str.c_str(), strW.c_str()); //Mac - XCode 3.2.6
```

Why is this difference in behavior? Is there any way to print std::string/char* in vswprintf in platform independent form?

Answer (score 0):

%hs is the platform independent way of printing char[] in both Win and Mac